# textarea not send form do not send form the first click to send. The at 2 click yes

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, tinymce-4

In a Tinymce textarea, it forces me to double click submit form. In the first send "var a" is empty, in the second click if you have the data and it is sent correctly. How can it be solved?

```
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/zgxpx6ymtwpuc7yy5x3wuic7eu7ughi6w7q98msfnxmbcpjp/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#comment',

    });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function FQB() {
    var a = document.forms["Formularioqr"]["comment"].value;


    if (a == null || a == "") {
      alert(a);
      return false;
    }else{
        a = a.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "send-email-manual-envio.php?mesaje=" + a + "&correo=<?php echo $correo;?>" ,
                                            dataType: "json",
                                                success: function() {
                                                        document.getElementById("Formularioqr").reset();
                                                        document.getElementById("showtextqr1").innerHTML =" Enviado Con exito ";
                                                },
                                                error: function() {
                                                        document.getElementById("Formularioqr").reset();
                                                        document.getElementById("showtextqr1").innerHTML = " ERROR!!";
                                                }
                                        });
    }
  }

</script>

  <form  method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="Formularioqr" name="Formularioqr" onsubmit="return FQB()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Mesaje:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="12" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
      <p id="showtextqr1"></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

Comment: why you have   two `var a`?

Comment: it is my mistake when copying the code on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but i would guess, that '.value' isn't working properly for tinymce textareas.. the tinymce has an dedicated function to get the content. See https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/

I would suggest, trying this way instead this `var a = document.forms["Formularioqr"]["comment"].value;`

Comment: is work fine var a = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(); and change This a = a.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');